# asp.net Jquery.ajax retaining JSON.Parse unexpected character error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

There are many questions based on this problem and i've read almost every one of them but none of their solutions seemed to work.
I've tried changing the data syntax for almost every possible one and i ended up removing the given data attribute but this still didnt solve my probem!
Í'm not highly experienced using jquery.Ajax but it seems to me that everything is correct!
 This exact same situation seemed to happen more often and the code which causes the error is in the Jquery library above version 1.8.
 
So i've changed my version 1.9 to 1.5.2 which should work but its still throwing this syntax error! :(

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
function ProcessLoginRequest() {
            try 
            {
                var pw = document.getElementById('<%= I_Password.ClientID %>').value;
                var un = document.getElementById('<%= I_Username.ClientID %>').value;                
                var enc = CryptoJS.SHA256(pw);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "~/User/Login.aspx/AJAX_LoginProcedure",
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d);
                    }
                }).done(function () {
                    alert("done");
                });
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
```

**ASP.NET C# CODE:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        //[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string AJAX_LoginProcedure()
        {
            string Username = string.Empty; 
            string Password = string.Empty;
            string SQL_ConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBString"].ConnectionString;
            string SQL_PW = WWLTemplate.SQL_FUNC.GET("Password", "Username", "=", Password, "DBName", SQL_ConnectString).ToString();
            if (Password == SQL_PW)
            {
                return true.ToString();
            }
            else
            {

                return false.ToString();
            }
        }
```

**Data syntax:**

1. [{Username: un, Password: enc}]
2. [{"Username": un, "Password": enc}]
3. "{'Username':'" + un +",'Password':'" + enc + "'}"
   I've also tried JSON.stringify() with every single one of these + a whole lot more options.
   I'm really out of options here, Can any of you spot the possible syntax error i made?
   I've read the documentation and tried a whole bunch of different methods but i just couldnt find a working way! :(

   Thanks for your time!
   -R

**EDIT:**
The problem is on the javascript side, it keeps throwing an SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character error. even if the code is blank.

Comment: Open the Developer Tools/Firebug on your browser and see the response ajax call in the network tab. Include the response in your question.

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
     if (Password == SQL_PW)
        {
             context.Response.Write("true");
        }
        else
        {

             context.Response.Write("false");
        }
   return;
```